# Java game crash twice on startup without error message

Tags: java, eclipse, crash, lwjgl

my friend's and I wrote a game in Java using LWJGL and Slick-Util.

In the main function, the first line I have is

```
    System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/natives/");
```

to set the path to the natives.

The game works fine in eclipse, the resources folder was copied exactly to the location of the exported jar, the libraries are definitely where they need to be: for some reason, on startup java reports a crash TWICE, and no error log is printed to the console (when run from command line). Is this something that may root from a common problem? Is there  good way to make error reporting more verbose? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, strangely enough, the native libraries were no longer linked in eclipse, yet it still runs in eclipse.

Comment: A guess: could you be trying to access a resource held by the jar file, such as an image, as a file rather than as a resource? Also, do you have any empty catch blocks in your code?

Comment: Not sure this is causing the problem or not but try using `System.getProperty("user.dir") + System.getProperty(File.separator) + "my folder" + System.getProperty(File.separator)`

Comment: The problem was that the version of LWJGL and the natives that I was including in the folder with the jar were not the same version.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy dlls used in jar to the folder that jar is in.(just put them near jar file)

Worked for my jmonkey-jocl benchmark http://forums.guru3d.com/showthread.php?t=379276

you may need an extra .bat file to start jvm with more RAM resource.

In the bat file:

```
 java -mx2048M -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=1 -XX:GCPauseIntervalMillis=60000 -XX:ConcGCThreads=2 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=2 -jar physics.jar
```

makes 2GB space for jvm, makes a custom garbage-collection way, runs physics.jar

```
 %~p0physics.jar %*  rather than just physics.jar
```

makes the addressing more flexible.

Comment: The dll's are where they should be, I'm trying the .bat file now